# Динамическая смена переменной Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Необходимо, в зависимости от ширины экрана, менять переменную `SERVICES_NUMBER_TO_DISPLAY` она управляет количество выводимого контента

Comment: PHP не может получить ширину экрана. Как вариант в вашем случае можно передать данные которые нужно отобразить из PHP в JS , там JS в зависимости от ширины сможет определить сколько выводить и сам может вывести.

Comment: Можно какой то пример небольшой с передачей переменной из PHP в JS

Comment: Ок, сейчас напишу

Answer (score 2):

PHP не может получить ширину экрана. Как вариант в вашем случае можно передать данные которые нужно отобразить из PHP в JS , там JS в зависимости от ширины сможет определить сколько выводить и сам может вывести.

Если Вы используете vue, то можно создать глобальный компонент который принимает в props нужные данные из PHP.

Если у Вас настроен дефолтный сетап vue + laravel, то можно сделать так:

#### Глобальная регистрация компонента:**

В файле **resources/assets/app.js**, например

```
Vue.component('show-tasks', require('./components/ShowTasks.vue'));
```

#### Использование компонента:

В blade вызывает глобальный компонент и передает ему параметры из PHP:

```
<show-tasks :json-data-from-php="{!! json_encode($data) !!}" />
<!-- Или -->
<show-tasks :json-data-from-php="@json($data)" />
```

В моем примере только оин параметр у компонента - `json-data-from-php`, но их может быть больше.

Сам компонент **ShowTasks.vue** может выглядеть так:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <!-- Это отобразит данные в шаблоне компонента -->
    <pre>{{ jsonDataFromPhp }}</pre>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ['jsonDataFromPhp'],
  mounted () {
    // показывает данные после отрисовки компонента в консоли
    console.dir(this.jsonDataFromPhp)
  }
}
</script>
```

Как это делать в интернете много инфы, удачи.

Comment: спасибо большое, буду пробовать!